# model.frame and update

Tags: r, formula, lm

In R, you might have estimated a model with a log-transformed dependent variable:

```
mfit <- lm(
    formula = log(salary) ~ yrs.service + yrs.since.phd, 
    data    = Salaries
  )
```

Then you might want to alter the model frame and call an update to refit the model:

```
n     <- nrow(Salaries)
mfr   <- model.frame(mfit)[sample(1:n, size=n, replace=TRUE),]
mfit2 <- update(mfit, data = mfr)
```

This will cause an error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'salary' not found
```

The reason is that the formula still has dependent variable `log(salary)` and the variable in the model frame is called `log(salary)`. R thinks that it can find `salary` and then call `log` on it. The same error would occur without the resampling, the example just shows why one might want to do it.

The procedure above is from a bootstrap package where resampling rows is performed. Is this behavior to be expected, or is it a bug? I know that one can get around it by transforming the variables in the data argument, but this seems annoying and overlooked...

Comment: it's not quite the same statistical model, but you could also fit `glm(salary~yrs.service + yrs.since.phd,family=gaussian(link="log"))`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sampling from `model.frame(mfit)`, you can sample from `na.omit(get_all_vars(myformula, Salaries))` instead. So, your example would become the following:

```r
myformula <- log(salary) ~ yrs.service + yrs.since.phd

mfit <- lm(formula = myformula, data = Salaries)

n       <- nrow(Salaries)
newdata <- na.omit(get_all_vars(myformula, Salaries))[sample(1:n, size=n, replace=TRUE),]
mfit2   <- update(mfit, data = newdata)
```

We can use the following simple example to confirm that `model.frame(myformula, df)` and `na.omit(get_all_vars(myformula, df))` select the same raw (untransformed) data from a data frame:

```r
df <- data.frame(w = rnorm(10), x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10))
df[1, 1] <- NA
df[2, 2] <- NA
df[3, 3] <- NA
df[4, 4] <- NA

identical(data.frame(na.omit(get_all_vars(z ~ w + x, df))), data.frame(model.frame(z ~ w + x, df)))
# [1] TRUE
```

Note that I wrapped the results of `na.omit(get_all_vars(...))` and `model.frame(...)` in `data.frame` just to drop the extraneous attributes for comparison purposes. Of course, `model.frame` does additional work, like log transforming the salary in your example. But if all you need to do is sample the original data, then `na.omit(get_all_vars(...))` works fine and then you can pass your new data frame to `lm` or `update`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's a bug. Since the formula can receive functions and operators, i.e.,

```
log(foo)*3 ~ abs(fooller) + fooz
```

It can't separate what's an object called `abs(fooller)` from the result of function `abs()` with the argument `fooller`.

In my point of view it's a problem of **naming conventions**. You shouln't name a variable, or column, as a name that can be misunderstood as a function. Instead you could use `salary.log`.

Comment: this is not actually a very useful answer. `abs(fooller)` is not a legal symbol/variable name in R (if you make a variable called <code>`abs(fooler)`</code> [i.e. backtick-protected], then you deserve what you get), and `all.vars()` can extract `fooller`